# Can't use angular-local-storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller, local-storage

This my code:

```
   angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$location', '$http','LocalStorageModule',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, localStorageService) {

        localStorageService.add('test', 'val');
]);
```

any Idea whats wrong?

I'm getting exception - unknown provider localstorageservice in the FF browser

Firebug Error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LocalStorageModuleProvider <-   LocalStorageModule
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/unpr?p0=LocalStorageModuleProvider%20%3C-     %20LocalStorageModule
    at http://127.1.0.0/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We should ask inejctor for  **`'localStorageService'`** instead of your *`'LocalStorageModule'`*

So the code should look like this:

```
angular
    .module('MyModule')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$location'
                                , '$http'
                                // instead of this
                                // ,'LocalStorageModule',
                                // use this
                                ,'localStorageService',
               function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, localStorageService) 
    {
        //localStorageService.add('test', 'val');
        localStorageService.set('test', 'val');
    }]);
```

And when we do initialize the module, we have to include the local storage module

```
angular
    .module('MyModule', [
       'LocalStorageModule', 
        ...
    ])
```

And also as documented here:

- [Angular Local Storage](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html)

we should use **`.set()`**

```
// To add to local storage
localStorageService.set('localStorageKey','Add this!');
```

Comment: I extended my answer with more explicit code snippet. Firstly check that the module creation does inject the `'LocalStorageModule'` and next use the service: `'localStorageService'`...