# angularjs - get from a factory returns null on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have two controllers(and two views) and a factory. I set a `property` in the factory from the first controller.Then I redirect to the second page. When I try to get the property from the factory in the second controller it works well. But when I refresh the page (view 2) the `get()` returns null..

What happens here?

**Factory**

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('Factory', function ($http, $location) {
        var factory = {},
            property = null;
       .....
       factory.set = function (data) {
            property = data;
        };

        factory.get = function () {
            return property;
        };
    return factory;
});
```

---

In the first controller I set

```
Factory.set($scope.property);
```

and redirect by

```
$location.path("/mypage/" + response.id);
```

**Second controller**

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('Controller2', function ($scope, $http, Factory) {

        $scope.property = Factory.get();
        alert($scope.property.key);
    });
```

Once I go to the second page the `alert` box pops up and shows the value of `key`. But when I refresh I get the following error on the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null
```

This is my **router.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/mypage', {
            templateUrl: 'mypage/Input.html',
            controller: 'Controller1'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/mypage/:id/', {
            templateUrl: 'mypage/Page.html',
            controller: 'Controller2'
        })
    }]);
```

Let me know if you need more details

Thanks..

Comment: Angular represents SPA. Browser refresh  === application restart. That is it

Comment: @RadimKöhler Is it possible to the data even after a refresh. (I know that if I pass all the values in the URL  I can get via routeParams.  I don't want this way)

Comment: There are few ways, how to keep data - persist them. E.g. use [local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25488033/1679310)

Comment: @user7 You shouldn't pas "all the values you can" in the URL. You should only pass the absolute necessary value to allow the second controller to get its data **from the backend**, using $http. You should get fresh, up-to-date information from the backend instead of relying on state that could have been loaded hours ago when maybe visiting a previous page.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks... Yes. That's what I'm going to do. I'm already passing the `id` in the URL. I'll use it to get the data from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the browser while in your second view, your url is pointing to /mypage/some_id. The browser reloads again and ngRoute routes you instantly to your second view. This means your Controller1 is not instantiated and hence the property in your Factory is not set.